# problem 19, section 3.2 book Chung - a course in probability path

Tags: probability

I can´t prove this problem. Can you help me? The problem says:

*If $\{X_n\}$ is a sequence of identically distributed random variables with finite mean, then
$$lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{E}\Big[\max_{1\leq j\leq n} |Xj|\Big] = 0$$
[HINT: Use Exercise 17 to express the mean of the maximum.]*

In problem 17 show that if X is a positive random variable, then we have
$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_0^\infty \!\! P(X > x)\, dx=\int_0^\infty \!\! P(X \geq x)\, dx$$

I prove the problem 19 assuming independence and for the general case I find some upper bounds for the maximum of dependent variables on the internet but none worked.

Thank you for help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Dominated convergence theorem after applying Exercise 17. The dominating function is P(|X_1|>x).

Comment: Thanks, I was seeing the problem in the wrong way and I forgot to apply the basic results.  The problem was easier than I thought.

Answer (score -1):

since h(x)=|f(x)| for any real valued function f, is a convex function(why?) then max(|Xi|) is also convex. by using Jensen's inequality you can prove this. be happy